# How to check an updated file and display its content?

Tags: python

I have a text file, and want to check it is updated and also display the updated content.

I tried using the last_modified_time and getting the checksum but how do i store it and use it for the next time

```
last_modified_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime)
hash1 = md5.new()
hash1.update("textfile.txt")
prevchecksum = hash1.digest()
```

Comment: What is "next time"? Next time you run the script?

Comment: this script would be running in every hour

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `unix`, maybe `stat` and `diff` command can do this:

```
root@Mc:~# echo "new" > a
root@Mc:~# echo "old" > b
root@Mc:~# diff a b
1c1
< new
---
> old
root@Mc:~# stat a
  File: 'a'
  Size: 4           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc01h/64513d    Inode: 1346        Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-05-05 06:52:52.898107822 +0000
Modify: 2017-05-05 06:52:48.434076120 +0000
Change: 2017-05-05 06:52:48.434076120 +0000
 Birth: -
```

From the man page [stat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat).

The Linux command `stat` is used for displaying status information of Linux files and file systems.

In Python, you can use `subprocess` module to execute shell command and get the result:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> status = subprocess.check_output(['stat','a'])
>>> status
"  File: 'a'\n  Size: 4         \tBlocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file\nDevice: fc01h/64513d\tInode: 1346        Links: 1\nAccess: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)\nAccess: 2017-05-05 06:52:52.898107822 +0000\nModify: 2017-05-05 06:52:48.434076120 +0000\nChange: 2017-05-05 06:52:48.434076120 +0000\n Birth: -\n"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but how do i compare the last and previous modified time??

Comment: how can i get the old content

Comment: @tintin  Maybe you can use a loop to store the last hash value or file content and modified time every 10s.